# How to fix baseboard header periodic buzzing

Tags: baseboard, noise, electric-heat

A baseboard heater in my apartment emits a short buzzing sound every 16-17 seconds. It seems to happen only when the room is near the temperature I've set on my thermostat, that is, only when the heater is keeping the room at a certain temperature, and not when it's working hard to raise the temperature. The buzzing isn't loud, but it's mildly irritating.

Does anyone know how to keep the heater quiet?

Answer (score 2):

Check the contacts in your thermostat and in the relay for your heater. It sounds like they're not opening completely when the desired temp is reached. If it's an old mechanical thermostat with the mercury switch, look for slag floating in the switch, in which case you'd want to replace it. If this is a rental unit, check with the landlord before doing any work and see if they'll correct the problem.